# Reducing closure overhead in Task.Run/Factory.StartNew with predefined object

Tags: c#, closures, task-parallel-library

This is purely for experimental purposes and/or a learning exercise. In essence, I'd like to see if I can reduce the footprint of the closure created when we use `Task.Run(()=>Func<>())` by creating a class that I initialize only once. One, the objective would be to avoid creating a 'new' instance of this every time we run, which would probably be less efficient than the closure itself I imagine (but this is mere speculation, I know). So, creating a basic class to do so is rather simple, as you can find examples of that here on the stack.

However, where I run into issue, is that it would appear to me, that if I want to use members and functions from another class, that having to encapsulate them, or inject them into the class we're going to `Run` on, while it may be less data than the original class itself, it's probably not going to be that much of an improvement.

So say, I have something along the lines of:

```
internal async Task<PathObject> PopulatePathObjectAsync(Vector3Int origin, Vector3Int destination, PathObject path)
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PopulatePathObject(origin, destination, path));
}

/// Not sure if we want to make this a task or not because we may just parallelize and await the outer task.
/// We'll have to decide when we get down to finalization of the architecture and how it's used.
internal PathObject PopulatePathObject(Vector3Int origin, Vector3Int destination, PathObject path)
{
    Debug.Log($"Pathfinding Search On Thread: ({System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId})");

    if (!TryVerifyPath(origin, destination, ref path, out PathingNode currentNode))
        return path;

    var openNodes = m_OpenNodeHeap;

    m_ClosedNodes.Clear();

    openNodes.ClearAndReset();
    openNodes.AddNode(currentNode);

    for (int i = CollectionBufferSize; openNodes.Count > 0 && i >= 0; i--)
    {
        currentNode = ProcessNextOpenNode(openNodes);

        if (NodePositionMatchesVector(currentNode, destination))
        {
            return path.PopulatePathBufferFromOriginToDestination(currentNode, origin, PathState.CompletePath);
        }

        ProcessNeighboringNodes(currentNode, destination);
    }

    return path.PopulatePathBufferFromOriginToDestination(currentNode, origin, PathState.IncompletePath);
}
```

In order to ditch the lambda, the closure, and the creation (or perhaps cast?) of the delegate, I would need a class that actually encapsulates that `PopulatePathObject` function in its entirety, either by literally copying the members necessary, or passing them as arguments. This all seems like it would probably render any benefits gained. So is there a way I could have something like..

```
private class PopulatePathObjectTask
{
    private readonly Vector2Int m_Origin;
    private readonly Vector3Int m_Destination;
    private readonly PathObject m_Path;

    public PopulatePathObjectTask(Vector2Int origin, Vector3Int destination, PathObject path)
    {
        m_Origin = origin;
        m_Destination = destination;
        m_Path = path;
    }

    public PathObject PopulatePathObject(Vector3Int origin, Vector3Int destination, PathObject path)
    {
        ///Obviously here, without access to the actual AStar class responsible for the search,
        ///I don't have access to the functions or the class members such as the heap or the hashset
        ///that represents the closed nodes as well as the calculated buffer size based on the space-state
        ///dimensions. With that, I'd just be recreating the class and not avoiding much, if any,
        ///of the overhead created by the closure capturing the class in the first place.
    }
}
```

That I could use to access the function that already exists? I've been toying with the idea of creating a static member and using dependency injection for the open/closed node collections, but I thought, or rather hoped, someone might have some more insight into this, other than it's pointless and the even *possible* overhead reduction or performance gains will be so minimal that it's pointless. Which, granted you're probably right, but I'm doing this as an exercise and I'd like to be able to actually measure the differences. I'm probably not even going to use it, might even ditch the AStar for JPS instead, but I would like to know before moving on. I'm not entirely sure, but it would seem as if the closure would have to have the entire AStar object captured in time, one would hope by reference.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question... are you trying to avoid the allocation of the async state machine? Or just the `() => PopulatePathObject(origin, destination, path)` delegate? You could save it to a static field to avoid some allocations. Also I think setting your class to sealed should give a small reduction in V-table lookups

Comment: And you should also not await the Task and just return it

Comment: @MateusZampol - I'm trying to avoid creating a new delegate and closure with every method call. The Task.Factory.StartNew is awaited because it needs to unwrap. Task.Factory.StartNew does't function as Task.Run does, it returns a Task<Task<TResult>> and awaiting it before you return unwraps the outer task.

Comment: That's not what the official documentation says tho. It also recommends using `Task.Run()` from .NET 4.5 onwards, unless you want to configure some options.

Comment: What documentation are you referring to? What part are you saying that it does not say? That it doesn't return Task<Task<TResult>>?

Task.Factory gives us some more options. Task.Run is shorthand for a Task.Factory call with no cancellation token, default task scheduler and set to deny children attached.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/

Comment: Yes, there are no nested Tasks, it wouldn't even make sense. It returns a `Task<TResult>`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is you're saying. Task.Factory.StartNew returns a nested task, it's not like Start.Run. Read the bottom of the documentation in the link I sent you. Only once you await it (or .Unwrap()) it, does it return a Task<TResult>

Comment: Yes, in the case of async delegates! Your delegate is not!

Comment: @MateusZampol Well, it turns out we were both wrong. I didn't read the intellisense when I first threw it together and it gave me a red underline and I assumed that was because it needed to be unwrapped so I awaited it. Oversight on my part, since the function call wasn't to an actual task. However, I can't just return it, I still have to await it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gladly, you can generalize the concept which was [mentioned by JonasH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77987300/13268855)

```
Task ExecuteActionAsync<TState>(
    Action<TState> callback, 
    TState state)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(static args => 
    {
        var local = (ValueTuple<TState, Action<TState>>)args;
        local.Item2(local.Item1);
    }, (state, callback));
}

Task<TResult> ExecuteFuncAsync<TState, TResult>(
    Func<TState, TResult> callback,
    TState state)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew<TResult>(static args => 
    {
        var local = (ValueTuple<TState, Func<TState, TResult>>)args;
        return local.Item2(local.Item1);
    }, (state, callback));
}
```

Notes:

- In order to avoid any extra closure based overhead the `StartNew`'s `action` parameter is declared as `static` which has compile time guarantees to avoid any closure usage.
- You need to cast the `args` to a `ValueTuple` because the `StartNew`'s overloads are using `Object` for `state` parameter
- As far as I know you can't cast to named tuples that's why the actual method call (`local.Item2(local.Item1)`) looks this ugly

You can add an extra line there to decompose the `ValueTuple` if you wish

```
var local = (ValueTuple<TState, Func<TState, TResult>>)args;
var (localCallback, localState) = (local.Item2, local.Item1);
return localCallback(localState);
```

Here is a sample usage

```
await ExecuteActionAsync(Console.WriteLine, 42);

var res = await ExecuteFuncAsync(_ => _, 42);
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Dotnet fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aHyTMA

---

To apply this to your use case

```
record struct PopulatePathArgs(Vector2Int origin, Vector3Int destination, PathObject path);

...
public PathObject PopulatePathObject(PopulatePathArgs args)

...

var result = await ExecuteFuncAsync(PopulatePathObject, new PopulatePathArgs(...));
//or more verbosely 
var result = await ExecuteFuncAsync(_ => PopulatePathObject(_), new PopulatePathArgs(...));
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

> I was not aware we could apply a static modifier to a lambda function

This feature was introduced in C# 9: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/static-anonymous-functions

> However, everything I can come up with or have seem, always has "new" somewhere.

Since you are working with an object oriented programming language that's should not be a big deal to new stuff. Even if you call `methodB` from `methodA` the runtime allocates memory because a new [`StackFrame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stackframe?view=net-8.0) is created.

If the allocated variables' scope is the function that means they will be cleaned up whenever you leave the function. If you have a closure then you want to access a variable outside of the scope of the original function. That's why an anonymous class is created (on your behalf) to capture those variables. So, with closure you are extending the lifecycle of the variables and the enclosing class is allocated on the heap. That object will be cleaned up later by the GC.

Both JonasH's and mine solutions are avoiding the usage of closure so, the allocated memory is cleaned up upon function exit. So, don't worry about memory allocation.

The drawback of the proposed solutions on the other hand that you have to define an enclosing data structure (record, class, struct, whatever).

> I've also read the discard operator can prevent memory allocation, but I've yet to measure that effect.

There you can also use `static` if you wish:

```
var res = await ExecuteFuncAsync(static _ => _, 42);
```

You can also define an Identity function if you wish, something like this:

```
public static class HelperFunctions
{
    public static T Identity<T>(T value) => value;
}
...

var res = await ExecuteFuncAsync(Identity, 42);
```

Comment: That's kind of the wall I keep running into. I appreciate your explanation, I was not aware we could apply a static modifier to a lambda function. However, everything I can come up with or have seem, always has "new" somewhere. I don't think it'd be so difficult for me to figure out if it was a function that returned nothing and had no parameters, but due to the fact I have to get the args from the call, it's starting to look to me like it's not possible. I had a friend suggest something I'll give a try, if I ever figure it out I'll let you guys know. Just kind of want to figure this out.

Comment: I've also read the discard operator can prevent memory allocation, but I've yet to measure that effect. Does this discard, in this circumstance, have an allocation or the creation of the closure, or is it only the static modifier? When I say, always has "new" I mean any alternative, obviously not with the lambda itself.

Comment: have an effect on* (won't let me edit now) Insert after  "in this circumstance"

Comment: @Grim_T I've updated my answer to address your concerns. Please check it again.

Comment: I'm not at all saying you haven't taught me something, I've actually learned a lot. The issue I'm facing is simply that I need to be able to supply the parameters in real time while using Task.Run/Factory.StartNew to offload it to the thread pool. I don't want to run it purely asynchronously because Unity is horribly inefficient and running it on the main thread is not such a great idea, especially considering the actually algorithm runs at .3ms on average and with the async overhead, with the state machine, the task scheduler, the closer, the delegate it's variable between 8-17ms.

Comment: Also, it's not really that this is going to make or break it, I just feel like there should be something much simpler.. like delcaring a func<Vector3Int, Vector3Int, PathObject, PathObject> and then populating the class member and being able to use it in Task.Factory.StartNew without having to incur the overhead with a new object. I appreciate the feedback, and I'll give it a shot, it just seems like, there should be a simpler solution to this because that's a lot of extra execution, still requires lambdas and new objects. I will however upvote it now that I can. Closure* in the prev comment.

Comment: While this honestly wasn't what I was looking for, as my objective was to declare an object once, and reuse it, I don't fault you for that as your explanation was very thorough and I'm not even sure what I want is possible. That said, I'm going to mark it as the accepted answer for the work you put in, which I greatly appreciate. Truly. Most of the times on stack, you don't run into great gentlemen like yourself these days. Much obliged.

Comment: And honestly, I know it seems absurd, but in the context of unity 'newing' stuff, is an issue. It's garbage collection isn't great. That's all.  It was really just a thought exercise that would have had the nice benefit of avoiding allocations because when we're talking about everything having to be done in 16ms and allocations multiple times per second, and the horrible monobehavior I do everything I can to avoid, new becomes a horrible sight in the code <3 Thanks again, I learned a lot.

Comment: @Grim_T Thank you. Unfortunately I'm unaware of a solution which you are looking for.